# Batch file why use double ==

Tags: batch-file

How come in a batch file, you use `if %foo%==bar` (that is, the double equals sign), Versus `set foo=bar` (where there is only one)?

Comment: I don't see any other thread explaining this . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is a general programming question:

While `=` signifies assigning a value:

```
var=5
// var is 5
```

A `==` signifies a comparison:

```
var==5
// is var 5
```

Though this technically doesn't work, examine this to understand why:

```
if((var=5)==8)
// This essentially says that "'Var is 5' is it 8"

// Instead of:
if((var=5)=8)
// Which says "'Var is 5' is 8"
```

Anyhow, in batch you should be using `EQU` instead of `==`.

Comment: @coltonon um.. I didn't downvote your question: whoever did probably thought you could have got your answer through google.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.  I just find that people here tend to explain things a bit better and more thoroughly.

Comment: @coltonon if u found my answer useful, please make it correct

Answer (score 2):

first hit in google from http://www.chebucto.ns.ca/~ak621/DOS/DOS-Char.html

> [ == ] (Double Equals) The "IF" command uses this to test if two
>   strings are equal:
>
> IF "%1" == "" GOTO HELP
>
> means that if the first parameter on the command line after the batch
>   file name is equal to nothing, that is, if a first parameter is not
>   given, the batch file is to go to the HELP label.
>
> ```
> This may be reversed by placing "NOT" after the command:
> ```
>
> IF NOT "%1" == "" GOTO ACTIONS
>
> So if the first parameter is not equal to nothing, that is, if it is
>   equal to something, the batch file is to go to the ACTIONS label.

A Single equals is used for variable assignment. Commonly seen with Set

```
SET [variable=[string]]
```

Comment: You did not explain the difference between `==` and `=`.